# Does CKEditor use log4j?

Tags: ckeditor, log4j

I would appreciate an answer to the question of whether CKEditor uses log4j.
We use an old version of CKEditor 3.6.x. In case the version should matter.

Answer (score 3):

CKEditor is written in JavaScript, have a read of their [homepage](https://ckeditor.com/).

Log4j is a Java logging tool.

Java and JavaScript are not the same thing. CKEditor does not use log4j.